# The file "image.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error in laravel while uploading two images

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have problem in uploading more than one images in Laravel. When I browse and choose one images then it working fine. But When I browse and choose two images then I got the error 'The file "image.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.'

ImageController.php

```
$featured = $request->file('image');
    $path=null;
    if(isset($featured)){
        $path = "images/";
        $year_folder = $path . date("Y");
        $month_folder = $year_folder . '/' . date("m");
            $path = "images/";
            $image_name = time().'.'.$featured->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = $month_folder . '/' . $image_name;
            $featured->move(public_path($month_folder), $image_name);
    }

    $featured_1 = $request->file('image_1');
    $path_1=null;
    if(isset($featured_1)){
        $path_1 = "images/";
        $year_folder = $path . date("Y");
        $month_folder = $year_folder . '/' . date("m");
            $path_1 = "images/";
            $image_name = time().'.'.$featured->getClientOriginalName();
            $path_1 = $month_folder . '/' . $image_name;
            $featured->move(public_path($month_folder), $image_name);
    }
```

This code is working fine if I choose one Image at a time but I got error when I choose both image simultaneously.

Comment: variable name error in image_2 code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code for image 2 upload :

```
$featured_1 = $request->file('image_1');
$path_1     = null;
if (isset($featured_1)) {
    $path_1       = "images/";
    $year_folder  = $path . date("Y");
    $month_folder = $year_folder . '/' . date("m");
    $path_1       = "images/";
    $image_name_2 = time() . '.' . $featured_1->getClientOriginalName();
    $path_1       = $month_folder . '/' . $image_name_2;
    $featured->move(public_path($month_folder), $image_name_2);
}
```

Comment: It was due $featured_1.